# Extract information from string before submitting to database

Tags: php, arrays, database

I want to extract some information from the code below. Such as user_name, user_email before it is submitted to the database.

As I understand it $user_info['user_field_fields'] are the databasefields and $user_info['user_field_inputs'] the values to be inserted in the correspondend fields.

```
$result = dbquery("INSERT INTO ".DB_USERS." (".$user_info['user_field_fields'].") VALUES (".$user_info['user_field_inputs'].")");
```

It would be nice if I can use a php code like this:

```
echo $user_name;

echo $user_email;

echo other_values;
```

Experimented with:

```
$data = array($user_info['user_field_fields'] => $user_info['user_field_inputs']);
```

And tried to show some values.
But I can't get it to work.

**Edit1:** Output of var_dump($user_info);
Hashes changed and anomized.

```
array(7) { ["user_name"]=> string(13) "Some username" ["user_password"]=> string(64) "0b27f3b44401f2633a1bbcf8447069f555be27eb3adce3ec2f53056ff65325" ["user_salt"]=> string(40) "78aefb9666662399cfaef1a76307777ab859f45" ["user_algo"]=> string(6) "sha256" ["user_email"]=> string(23) "some@email.com" ["user_field_fields"]=> string(331) "user_name, user_algo, user_salt, user_password, user_email, user_hide_email, user_avatar, user_posts, user_threads, user_joined, user_lastvisit, user_ip, user_ip_type, user_rights, user_groups, user_level, user_status, user_location, user_zip, user_inetpakket, user_modem, user_router, user_tvpakket, user_tvkpakket, user_ontvanger" ["user_field_inputs"]=> string(297) "'Some username', 'sha256', '78aefb9666662399cfaef1a76307777ab859f45', '0b27f3b44401f2633a1bbcf8447069f555be27eb3adce3ec2f53056ff65325', 'some@email.com', '1', '', '0', '0', '1388665205', '0', '183.81.50.14', '4', '', '', '101', '0', 'Amsterdam', '1000AA', '1', '', '', '1', '', '1601'" }
```

**Edit2**: Working code with solution from **Ushakov Nik**

```
$user_field_fields = explode(', ', $user_info['user_field_fields']); // for getting array of fields
$user_field_inputs = explode(', ', $user_info['user_field_inputs']); // for getting values
foreach($user_field_inputs as $k => $val) { $user_field_inputs[$k] = trim($val, "'"); }
$data= array_combine($user_field_fields, $user_field_inputs);
extract($data);
$data= "user_name: ".$user_name."<br />user_email: ".$user_email."<br />http://whois.domaintools.com/".$user_ip;
```

$data will be send by email to admin for spam prevention on rarely monitored sites.

Comment: Try var_dump( $user_info ); to see what the array looks like (and let us know the output if you still need help)

Comment: Added Output of var_dump($user_info); See Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you sure that fields and values are in the same order then you can use

[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$data = array_combine($user_info['user_field_fields'], $user_info['user_field_inputs']);
```

it will give you something like

```
array(
    'user_email' => 'ex@example.com',
    'user_name' => 'Some Name'
)
```

Then you can do [extract](http://php.net/extract)

```
extract($data);
```

then you will be able to use variables that you want

**EDIT**

After you added output of `var_dump($user_info);` it is obvious that i made mistake: it is strings! So you need some preparations.

```
$user_field_fields = explode(', ', $user_info['user_field_fields']); // for getting array of fields

$user_field_inputs = explode(', ', $user_info['user_field_inputs']); // for getting values
```

Every element of `$user_field_inputs` must be trimmed to cut out quote characters

```
foreach($user_field_inputs as $k => $val) {
    $user_field_inputs[$k] = trim($val, "'");
}
```

and now you can do

```
$data = array_combine($user_field_fields, $user_field_inputs);
```

and so on

Comment: This works! :) Sorry for not including var_dump($user_info) in my initial question.